# Context menu icon in BureauBlue theme

Tags: wpf, icons, themes, contextmenu

I am using the BureauBlue theme in my application.

I have created a `ContextMenu` with some icons, and when I select an item on this menu, the icon is not displayed.

So, what is the problem?!

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the probem. Just must change the order of `MenuItem ControlTemplate` items and place `Icon ContentPresenter` **after** `BackgroundGradientOver Rectangle`!

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="BackgroundGradientOver" Stroke="#FFDBCE99" Opacity="0" Fill="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}"/>
<ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon" />
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

It's bug in BureauBlue theme.

You can fix it by change style for `MenuItem`.

Find style for `MenuItem` in "BureauBlue.xaml" and change it with following style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HighlightOn">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientOver" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HighlightOff">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientOver" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="17" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="14" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon" />

                        <Grid Visibility="Hidden" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="GlyphPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanelpath" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,2 L0,4.8 L2.5,7.4 L7.1,2.8 L7.1,0 L2.5,4.6 z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="BackgroundGradientOver" Stroke="#FFDBCE99" Opacity="0" Fill="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}"/>

                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="HeaderHost" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Header" />

                        <Grid Grid.Column="3" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="ArrowPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" x:Name="SubMenuPopup" Focusable="false" AllowsTransparency="true" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" VerticalOffset="-3">
                            <Grid x:Name="SubMenu">
                                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" >
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource WhiteColor}"/>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>

                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>

                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1,0,1" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,6,3" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true" />
                        <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" TargetName="SubMenuPopup" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1,0,1" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,6,3" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" TargetName="SubMenuPopup" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="GlyphPanel" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="AllowsTransparency" SourceName="SubMenuPopup" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,3,3" TargetName="SubMenu" />
                        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" TargetName="SubMenu" />
                        <Setter Property="BitmapEffect" Value="{DynamicResource PopupDropShadow}" TargetName="SubMenuBorder" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HighlightOff}" x:Name="HighlightOff_BeginStoryboard" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HighlightOn}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove `Rectangle`, and all his storyboards and instead is to write the following line in a trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" />
</Trigger>
```

Full style of `MenuItem`:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">                        
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="17" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="14" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon" />

                            <Grid Visibility="Hidden" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="GlyphPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanelpath" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,2 L0,4.8 L2.5,7.4 L7.1,2.8 L7.1,0 L2.5,4.6 z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
                            </Grid>

                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="HeaderHost" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Header" />

                            <Grid Grid.Column="3" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="ArrowPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z" />
                            </Grid>

                            <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" x:Name="SubMenuPopup" Focusable="false" AllowsTransparency="true" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" VerticalOffset="-3">
                                <Grid x:Name="SubMenu">
                                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" >
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource WhiteColor}"/>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>

                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1,0,1" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,6,3" />
                            <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true" />
                            <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" TargetName="SubMenuPopup" />
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1,0,1" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,6,3" />
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2" />
                            <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2" />
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" TargetName="SubMenuPopup" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="GlyphPanel" />
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="AllowsTransparency" SourceName="SubMenuPopup" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,3,3" TargetName="SubMenu" />
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" TargetName="SubMenu" />
                            <Setter Property="BitmapEffect" Value="{DynamicResource PopupDropShadow}" TargetName="SubMenuBorder" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```